# Win XP Pro install CD says it can't upgrade from Win 2K Pro

Tags: windows-xp, windows-2000

Everything I've read and heard tells me that I should be able to perform an upgrade from Windows 2000 Pro to Windows XP Pro instead of a clean install.  One blogger went as far as to say that there are only a few files that are different between the two OS's, although I highly doubt that.

So why when I put in my Win XP Pro install CD did it tell me that it cannot upgrade from Win 2K pro to Win XP pro?  I also tried booting from the XP pro install CD and it didn't even have any options for upgrading.

Comment: You won't have a option to upgrade booting from the disk. Only from within your Windows 2000 install. If you don't have that option, the I suspect Peter is right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is it an OEM disk?  I believe they are handicapped and cannot be used for upgrades.

Comment: Yes, I guess it is an OEM disk.  Darn.  I was hoping I could upgrade.

Comment: If you can get your hands on a VLK disc, do the upgrade, then use a tool called Role Switcher to change it to the appropriate license you have; I'm not sure of the 'legalities' of this, but it is a potential solution :)